# Has anyone had a problem with tsParticles appearing only when you resize window?

Tags: typescript, resize, window

So tsParticles works for me on index and contact html page, but doesnt work on two other pages until I resize window width..
Has anyone had similar problem?
I don't get error in the console or anything, just doesn't show until resized.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you update your question with a minimal reproducible code? An example of the code that you use to initialize tsParticles and to include it in html should be sufficient.

Comment: This happened some versions ago, the version `1.18.11` should fix this issue. This issue was (probably, without code I can't say) given from collisions enabled, a small canvas/window, and a high number of particles since particles can't be placed correctly.

Comment: Can you check out the code on the link https://petramarkovic.github.io/portfolio/index.html ? The code is too big so i think its easier like this. You'll notice that on the homepage and contact page partciles appear, but on the about and portfolio page they dont until you resize.

Comment: I've checked your config, you have collisions enabled as I thought initially. But that's not the issue. You are hiding the main container to display the loading animation in those pages and that makes tsParticles calculate the canvas size to `0`. tsParticles refresh is triggered only on `window` resize event, you can try to trigger it or to load tsParticles later.